# Casting & Inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, type-conversion

I encountered a piece of code similar to the one below and was sure that its output would be `B`, since the variable `y` is cast to `class B` before calling `x()`, but instead, the program prints `C`. So I have two questions:

1. Why is `C.x()` called instead of `B.x()`? Why does Java remember a variable's original type after it's been cast to a new type?
2. How would I call `B.x()`?

```java
class A {
    public void x() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void x() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    @Override
    public void x() {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A y = new C();
        ((B)y).x();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because casting does not change any type. It really is not up to you to decide to call `B.x()`.

Comment: (1) Polymorphic methods (those which are not final, or private or static) don't care about type of *variable* but only care about type of *object* on which method is executed. That is what polymorphism is all about.

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting because I tried out the same thing in C++ and the output was B. In C#, though, the output was C as well. Slightly confusing.